# Plugin (vim-latex) crashing gVim on startup

Tags: vim, latex

I'm trying to use [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download#advanced) with gVim on Windows XP, but as soon as I open a .tex file (or as soon as I `set ft=tex`) gVim crashes with no error messages visible. The crash doesn't occur in console vim.

I've followed the setup instructions to a T (as far as I can tell), and I've tried disabling all other plugins and stripping my .vimrc as well.

I tried running `gvim -V9log.txt file.tex`, but the output didn't help me, I'll include it here in case you can get anything useful from it.

```
could not source "$VIM\vimrc"
sourcing "$HOME\_vimrc"
Searching for "filetype.vim" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim"
line 2: sourcing "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftdetect/*.vim" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after\ftdetect/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after\ftdetect/*.vim"
not found in 'runtimepath': "ftdetect/*.vim"
line 2497: sourcing "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/menu.vim"
Searching for "autoload/paste.vim" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles\autoload/paste.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles\autoload/paste.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\autoload/paste.vim"
line 156: sourcing "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\autoload\paste.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\autoload\paste.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\menu.vim
finished sourcing C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/menu.vim
continuing in C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim
finished sourcing C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim
continuing in C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson\.vimrc
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after\filetype.vim"
Searching for "ftplugin.vim" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles\ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles\ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\ftplugin.vim"
line 2: sourcing "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\ftplugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\ftplugin.vim
continuing in C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson\.vimrc
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after\ftplugin.vim"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after\ftplugin.vim"
finished sourcing $HOME\_vimrc
Searching for "plugin/**/*.vim" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/**/*.vim"
sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim
sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/filebrowser.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/filebrowser.vim
sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/imaps.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/imaps.vim
sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/libList.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/libList.vim
sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/remoteOpen.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/plugin/remoteOpen.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/plugin/**/*.vim"
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
sourcing "C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Program Files/Vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/plugin/**/*.vim"
sourcing "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
finished sourcing $VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim
could not source "$VIM\gvimrc"
could not source "$HOME\_gvimrc"
could not source "$VIM\_gvimrc"
chdir(C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73)
chdir(C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson)
Searching for "bitmaps/Open.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Open.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Open.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Open.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Open.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Open.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Open.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Save.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Save.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Save.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Save.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Save.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Save.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Save.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveAll.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Print.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Print.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Print.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Print.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Print.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Print.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Print.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Undo.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Undo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Undo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Undo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Undo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Undo.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Undo.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Redo.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Redo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Redo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Redo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Redo.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Redo.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Redo.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Cut.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Cut.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Cut.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Cut.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Cut.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Cut.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Cut.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Copy.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Copy.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Copy.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Copy.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Copy.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Copy.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Copy.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Paste.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Paste.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Paste.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Paste.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Paste.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Paste.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Paste.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Replace.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Replace.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Replace.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Replace.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Replace.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Replace.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Replace.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/FindNext.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/FindNext.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/FindNext.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/FindNext.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/FindNext.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/FindNext.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindNext.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindPrev.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/LoadSesn.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/SaveSesn.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/RunScript.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/RunScript.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/RunScript.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/RunScript.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/RunScript.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/RunScript.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunScript.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Make.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Make.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Make.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Make.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Make.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Make.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Make.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/RunCtags.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/TagJump.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/TagJump.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/TagJump.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/TagJump.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/TagJump.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/TagJump.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/TagJump.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/Help.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/Help.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/Help.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/Help.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Help.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/Help.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/Help.bmp"
Searching for "bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp"
not found in 'runtimepath': "bitmaps/FindHelp.bmp"
Reading viminfo file "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson\_viminfo" info oldfiles
"testfile.tex" [New File]
Reading viminfo file "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson\_viminfo" marks
Executing BufNewFile Auto commands for "*.tex"
autocommand call s:FTtex()

Executing FileType Auto commands for "*"
autocommand call s:LoadFTPlugin()

Searching for "ftplugin/tex.vim ftplugin/tex_*.vim ftplugin/tex/*.vim" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/tex.vim"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/tex_*.vim"
line 17: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim"
line 8: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim"
Searching for "ftplugin/tex/texrc" in "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles,C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73,C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after,C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/tex/texrc"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/tex/texrc"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73/ftplugin/tex/texrc"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/tex/texrc"
Searching for "C:\Documents and Settings\nknowlson/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/tex/texrc"
not found in 'runtimepath': "ftplugin/tex/texrc"
line 31: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/texrc"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/texrc
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 808: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/texproject.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/texproject.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 811: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/texmenuconf.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/texmenuconf.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 812: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim"
line 13: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/wizardfuncs.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/wizardfuncs.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/envmacros.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 813: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/elementmacros.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/elementmacros.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 819: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/mathmacros.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/mathmacros.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 822: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/multicompile.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/multicompile.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 823: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/compiler.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 824: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/folding.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/folding.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 825: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/templates.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 826: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/custommacros.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/custommacros.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 827: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/bibtex.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/bibtex.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 831: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/brackets.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/brackets.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 832: sourcing "C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/smartspace.vim"
finished sourcing C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/smartspace.vim
continuing in C:/Documents and Settings/nknowlson/vimfiles/ftplugin/latex-suite/main.vim
line 8
```

Please let me know if there is any more information I can provide you with.

**EDIT :** Here is a normal/successful [startup log](https://gist.github.com/1141181) using -V9 as well (linked to avoid making this needlessly long). It also has some odd looking lines like:

```
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim/vimfiles\filetype.vim"
Searching for "C:\Program Files\Vim\vim73\filetype.vim"
```

So it's probably not the mixed slashes that are causing problems.

**EDIT2 :** If you know other approaches to debugging vim plugin problems I would love to hear those as well!

Comment: I would say that this is off-topic here - it does not relate to software development, even if vim is often used as a tool for that. I think it would belong to superuser.com, though maybe tex.stackexchange.com could also be suitable (as this is about a LaTeX editor). (I'm voting for closing and migration to superuser.)

Comment: There are 4,359 questions tagged vim on SO, most don't directly reference software development in them. I'm curious as to why you think this isn't appropriate here. Also, I am (going to be) using latex to write some of the documentation for a software package. So I definitely don't think it's more suited to superuser. Possibly tex.SO if you really think it doesn't belong here.

Comment: ok, I unmigrated it. You should edit this a bit to improve it so it gets bumped.

Comment: Unfortunately, no :( Ended up on some other tasks, haven't had the time to go back to it.

Comment: I'm having similar problem on win 7. The only difference is that I got it working, and used it for a month or two, but then one day it suddenly started crashing. Logs doesn't say much as well. Maybe some dll got updated? Normal vim is working fine, it's only gvim that's having problem, so maybe it's connected with the context menu which latex suite adds on top. Maybe there's a way to turn it off...

Answer (score 2):

As some follow up. I've recently tried this on Windows 7 with gvim 7.3 and [this](https://github.com/jcf/vim-latex) version of vim-latex without problems.

Comment: Unfortunately that same vim-latex is not working on my Windows 7 gvim 7.3.829, same crash problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather old question but it is still unresolved.
Facts are:

- GVim 7.3
- Win XP
- latest vim-latex plugin
- It crashes if "filtype plugin on" is set
- It crashes if there any \begin{...} statements; if those are commented out it
  will not crash!

Answer (score 2):

I guess vijayvithal is on the right track. 
Probably the root cause in Windows is a non standard or changed python.exe location.

```
C:\Python27\python.exe
```

In my case it is Anaconda distribution. The same symptom as reported for latex-suite can be observed in this case when doing

```
:python print "goodbye world!
```

Not sure how to change the python path used in vim maybe it is defined during compilation?
If someone knows we would have the solution for the problem.

Workarounds:

1) vijayvithal suggestions

2) Seperate python installation only for vim

Answer (score 1):

The following answer from [Capture Vim's error output before it crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225367/capture-vims-error-output-before-it-crashes)

helped resolve my issue

add the following line to your ~/_vimrc file

`let g:Tex_UsePython=0`